# How to stop repeating the letter

Tags: python

This code is use to pick the capital city from a list : capitals = ('Kabul', 'Tirana (Tirane)', 'Algiers', 'Andorra la Vella', 'Luanda', "Saint John's", 'Buenos Aires') when I type print(get_funny_case_capital_cities("u")) the output becomes: 'kabBuLl', 'lLuAanda', 'bBuEenos aires'

The code is to only pick the city include a certain letter, in this case "u" and then capitalized the immediate neighbour of "u"

This is my code, I want to e.g. print letter before and after "u" capitalized such as bRuSsels but then with my code, it becomes brRuSssels, I wonder why

```py
def get_funny_case_capital_cities(letter):
    result = []

    for country, capital in zip(countries, capitals):
        if letter.lower() in capital.lower():
            funny_case_capital = []

            for i in range(len(capital)):
                char = capital[i].lower()

                if char == letter.lower():
                    # Capitalize the previous and next letters
                    prev_char = capital[i - 1].upper() if i > 0 and capital[i - 1].isalpha() else ''
                    next_char = capital[i + 1].upper() if i < len(capital) - 1 and capital[i + 1].isalpha() else ''
                    funny_case_capital.append(prev_char + char + next_char)
                else:
                    funny_case_capital.append(char)

            result.append("".join(funny_case_capital))

    return result
```

I just don't know what's wrong

Comment: Can you provide some input and outputs

Comment: this code is use to pick the capital city from a list : capitals = ('Kabul', 'Tirana (Tirane)', 'Algiers', 'Andorra la Vella', 'Luanda', "Saint John's", 'Buenos Aires')

when I type print(get_funny_case_capital_cities("u"))

the output becomes: 'kabBuLl', 'lLuAanda', 'bBuEenos aires'

Comment: The code is to only pick the city include a certain letter, in this case "u" and then capitalized the immediate neighbour of "u"

Comment: Please [edit] the supplementary information into your question. Each question should stand on its own, comments are for asking clarifications and may be deleted in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're seeing duplicating letters around the letter `u` is that those letters neighboring `u` are already appended to `funny_case_capital` in their own iteration through `funny_case_capital.append(char)` in the `else` clause, making `prev_char` and `next_char` duplicates (despite different casings) in `prev_char + char + next_char`.

Instead of appending letters to an output list, you can convert the string to a list first and then assign converted letters by index as necessary:

```
def funnycase(string, letter):
    letter = letter.lower()
    chars = list(string)
    size = len(string)
    for i, char in enumerate(string.lower()):
        if char == letter:
            for j in i - 1, i + 1:
                if 0 <= j < size:
                    chars[j] = string[j].upper() if string[j].isalpha() else ''
    return ''.join(chars)
```

or instead of making neighboring letters uppercase when you encounter `u` in the iterations, you can make a letter uppercase when it is found to have `u` as a neighbor:

```
def funnycase(string, letter):
        letter = letter.lower()
        chars = list(string)
        size = len(string)
        for i, char in enumerate(string.lower()):
            if i < size - 1 and string[i + 1] == letter or i > 0 and string[i - 1] == letter:
                chars[i] = char.upper() if char.isalpha() else ''
        return ''.join(chars)
```

so that:

```
print(funnycase('brussels', 'u'))
```

outputs:

```
bRuSsels
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you are appending the capitalized letters to the city name, when they should be replaced by the capitalized version of the letters.

You could try something like:

```
def get_funny_case_capital_cities(letter, countries, capitals):
    result = []

    for country, capital in zip(countries, capitals):
        if letter.lower() in capital.lower():
            funny_case_capital = list(capital)  # Convert to list for easier manipulation

            for i, char in enumerate(capital):
                if char.lower() == letter.lower():
                    # Capitalize the letter before, if it exists
                    if i > 0:
                        funny_case_capital[i - 1] = capital[i - 1].upper()
                    # Capitalize the letter after, if it exists
                    if i < len(capital) - 1:
                        funny_case_capital[i + 1] = capital[i + 1].upper()

            result.append("".join(funny_case_capital))

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

**The main problem is that you append the previous and next char each time**, which results in duplicate chars. To do this, you need to update the previous char instead of appending a new one. You can also use a flag to check if you need to append the next char capitalize or not.

**Your code can also provide IndexError exception if the letter be equal to the first char of capital**. so you need to check the index before updating or accessing to previous index.

a full code can be like this:

```
def get_funny_case_capital_cities(letter):
    result = []

    for country, capital in zip(countries, capitals):
        if letter.lower() in capital.lower():
            funny_case_capital = []
            # we define a flag to control wether capitalize next letter or not
            capitalize_next_letter = False
            for i in range(len(capital)):
                char = capital[i].lower()

                if char == letter.lower():
                    # We only capitalize prev char if index is greater that zero. to prevent IndexError error.
                    if i > 0:
                      # to capitalize prev char, simply update the prev index (not appending)
                      prev_char = capital[i - 1].upper() if i > 0 and capital[i - 1].isalpha() else ''
                      funny_case_capital[-1] = prev_char #aka funny_case_capital[-1].upper()
                    # every time we want to add a letter, we should check capitalize_next_letter flag
                    if capitalize_next_letter:
                        capitalize_next_letter = False
                        funny_case_capital.append(char.upper())
                    else:
                        funny_case_capital.append(char)
                    # set capitalize_next_letter flag true to add next char with capital letter
                    capitalize_next_letter = True
                else:
                    # againg, when we want to add a letter, we should check capitalize_next_letter flag
                    if capitalize_next_letter:
                        capitalize_next_letter = False
                        funny_case_capital.append(char.upper())
                    else:
                        funny_case_capital.append(char)

            result.append("".join(funny_case_capital))

    return result
```